# View the number pending requests to access a locked row or table?

Tags: oracle, concurrency, locking

I understand that, in Oracle, you can check what rows or tables are locked and who is locking them, but is there a way to see how many pending requests are in queue trying to access that information at any given time?

I know that anything that would require an active verification of this is probably bad practice.  I'm just trying to show something to someone and that would help me greatly get my point across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [`DBA_WAITERS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/statviews_5087.htm) show what you're looking for? You can join to `V$SESSION` to see who is holding the lock and who is waiting for the resource, or other views to get other information. I'm not sure if that's quite what you're after though.

Comment: Many thanks good sir, that is precisely what I was looking for! Great!